# Rendering vertical line in FusionChart after the last column on X Axis

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

The following array represents my X-Axis metadata for Fusion Chart (bar graph). My requirement is to render a vertical line if the date is *today* i.e. current date.

So eg: if *today* is `Wed 30-Aug-2011`, I insert a vertical line object in the array. This works fine, a line is appropriately rendered.

However, if *today* is `Wed 31-Aug-2011`, I insert the `vline` object at the end of the array. This time, fusion charts does not render the vertical line.

[This page](http://kb.fusioncharts.com/questions/278/How+do+I+customize+the+vertical+lines+on+the+chart?) states that vertical line can be placed between any two data points.

I understand that there are no *two* data points in this case (i.e. `vline` object is not between two data points) but is there a way to still render the line?
I found a hack which is to insert a blank label after the `vline` object but again, it's a hack, it creates a noticeable blank area at the right end. Do we have a *proper* solution? or it is a limitation that I have to deal with?

```
[
    {
        "label": "Mon 01-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 02-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Wed 03-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Thu 04-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fri 05-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sat 06-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sun 07-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mon 08-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 09-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Wed 10-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Thu 11-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fri 12-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sat 13-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sun 14-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mon 15-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 16-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Wed 17-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Thu 18-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fri 19-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sat 20-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sun 21-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mon 22-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 23-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Wed 24-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Thu 25-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fri 26-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sat 27-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sun 28-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mon 29-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 30-Aug-2011"
    },       
    {
        "label": "Wed 31-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "vline": "true",
        "thickness": "2",
        "dashed": "1",
        "linePosition ": "0",
        "dashGap": "2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack would be:

Put the vline definition just before the last category and set `linePosition: 1` as shown below:

```
[
    {
        "label": "Mon 01-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 02-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Wed 03-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Thu 04-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fri 05-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sat 06-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sun 07-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mon 08-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 09-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Wed 10-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Thu 11-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fri 12-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sat 13-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sun 14-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mon 15-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 16-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Wed 17-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Thu 18-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fri 19-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sat 20-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sun 21-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mon 22-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 23-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Wed 24-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Thu 25-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Fri 26-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sat 27-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Sun 28-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Mon 29-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "label": "Tue 30-Aug-2011"
    },
    {
        "vline": "true",
        "thickness": "2",
        "dashed": "1",
        "linePosition ": "1",
        "dashGap": "2"
    },       
    {
        "label": "Wed 31-Aug-2011"
    }
]
```

Make sure you have set `canvasPadding` or hide the canvas-border to ensure that the vline is not overlapping with the canvas-border.

Comment: Well this works :) A better(?) hack than the one I mentioned! :P This would be my last resort! Is this is a limitation of FusionCharts? Can't we have a hack-free solution?